# Is a 51cm frame road bike the correct size for someone almost 6ft?

Tags: road-bike

Looking for some advice on my first road bike.

I've had my eye on a [Carerra Virtuoso](http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_810675_langId_-1_categoryId_165710) for about 6 months now, they haven't budged from £350, however I've just spotted [one on ebay](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=190483168129&ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWAX%3aIT) second hand.

None of my local stores have this bike in stock, otherwise I'd go sit on it to size it up.

Being 5'11" (about 180cm) and 194 lbs, would I be too big/small for this bike?

I currently have a [22" Carerra Kraken](http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_518229_langId_-1_categoryId_165499) and that feels about right size wise

Also, bearing in mind they are £350 new from halfords (and I have £50 halfords vouchers..), how much would be a reasonable bid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the website:

> Large bottom bracket to top tube = 51cm which is equivalent to our standard 58cm frame

51cm sounds too small for you; 58cm might be ok or it could be too big.  But there is no substitute for actually trying out the bike, or at least something similar to it.  Your leg, arm and torso lengths all have an effect on how well any bike will fit you and it's based on more than just the seat tube length.

Remember that a bike that's comfortable and fits you well will be more fun to ride.  Good fit is more important than weight or colour -- or even price -- so choose wisely.

Answer (score 4):

I'm 5'8" and have ridden a 56cm frame (Kestrel) and now 54cm (Orbea). Each manufacturer will fit differently based on the other tube lengths, the position of the seat stays, etc.

Darkcanuck's post from the website makes me think you may be ok, though it could be on the smaller side. I prefer riding a frame on the smaller side though.

If you're about 6' and this is their "large" frame, instinct tells me it's probably the right fit. 51cm sounds really small though, not knowing the other details, so I wouldn't consider that your "normal" size for other bikes.

Comment: I think that you mean 56cm/54cm frame, not 56"/54"(inch) frame? A 56" is 1.4m!

Comment: Actually, I have very freakishly long legs... Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

"Pubic Bone Height", basically your standover height, is the main measurement to consider when sizing a bike. Not overall body height.

There are many other factors, so until you sit a given geometry, you can't really know if fits you.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your inseam. I'm 6' and typically ride a 58 or 59cm road frame, or a 19" mtn. frame. My inseam is 33". Your torso to inseam ratio matters a great deal, as some frames will have a longer top tube to seat tube ratio than others. There is no substitute for a test ride.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be too small. 22 inches is 56cm so I think a 51cm. frame would be too small for you. I'm 183cm and use a 56cm. road frame, that's approximately what you should be looking for. You could enlarge the bike using longer seatpost and stem.

For mountain bike I use a 18 inches frame which fits me correctly too. If I'm not wrong road and mountain bike frame sizes are calculated differently.

Comment: 51cm is considered a "large" frame, they have a medium but no other sizes :S

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not a specialist, I just gave you my point given my experience. You may ask them for which height range they recommend this frame then.

Answer (score 1):

Someone nearing 6' should be on a 54-57cm frame, depending on reach, inseam and geometry.